# Different events for different link clicks

Tags: javascript, events, hyperlink

I am making a website and I'm not very expert on javascript language, so I would like to ask you this question:

I have 4 links (1,2,3,4) and 2 div (image, menu).

I would like that both "image" and "menu" fade away when i click links 1 and 2, while only image to fade away when links 3 and 4 are clicked. This should happen before page is redirected to link location.

Is it possible to achieve? How?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. =)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery, because it will make your job quite easy. You can read about jQuery selectors, .fadeOut() and how to prevent links from redirecting you immediately.

I can provide some code if you can't do it by yourself, but I have to ask : Why do you want to hide/fade away something when the user is eventually redirected to another location?

Comment: Thank you very much! I already know how to use fadein and out function, also for redirecting. right now i am using:
$("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("#image;#menu").fadeOut(600, redirectPage);     
    });         
    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    };

});

This code currently works.
The problem is that instead of a general $("a") i would like it to be something like (if click link 1 or 2 than fade only #image, otherwise fade both #image and #menu).

Comment: I just want to make a fade effect transition within my website pages.
Thanks!

Comment: then add unique id to all the elements and bind the click event to them, like this: $('#linkA").click(......); $('#linkB').click(...) and so on

Comment: ok so you suggest me to write the code above for each of the link? wouldn't it become too long with 5 or 6 link?
I'm not expert but i was wondering if this makes loading the page much longer. thanks!

Comment: So you want unique action for each link and yet want to write generic code? - not going to work. If more than one elements do the same when clicked then you should read about jQuery selectors and see how you can select more than one with one expression. And don't worry about the page loading time, you need more than few lines to drastically increase the loading time. If you want to measure, start Chrome and press F12 and exprore the Network tab.